# Empty disks in Redshift Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have two nodes 8xl cluster. And today I've decided to take a look at some metrics that Amazon provides, what I've noticed is that some disks are empty.

From Amazon docs:

```
capacity    integer     Total capacity of the partition in 1 MB disk blocks.
```

SQL:

```
select owner, used, tossed, capacity, trim(mount) as mount
from stv_partitions
where capacity < 1;
 owner | used | tossed | capacity |   mount   
-------+------+--------+----------+-----------
     0 |    0 |      1 |        0 | /dev/xvdo
     1 |    0 |      1 |        0 | /dev/xvdo
(2 rows)
```

Can someone explain to me why am I seeing this? Is that an expected behaviour?

### Updated:

```
 owner | host | diskno |  part_begin   |   part_end    | used | tossed | capacity | reads | writes | seek_forward | seek_back | is_san | failed | mbps |                                                                                                                              mount                                                                                                                               
-------+------+--------+---------------+---------------+------+--------+----------+-------+--------+--------------+-----------+--------+--------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1 |    1 |     13 |             0 | 1000126283776 |    0 |      1 |        0 |     0 |      0 |            0 |         0 |      0 |      1 |    0 | /dev/xvdo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
     0 |    1 |     13 | 1000126283776 | 2000252567552 |    0 |      1 |        0 |     0 |      0 |            0 |         0 |      0 |      1 |    0 | /dev/xvdo
```

Comment: Can you please provide the complete record information from stv_partitions ?

Comment: I meant the complete tuple instead of just printing few columns from this table. i.e Select * from stv_partitions where capacity < 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the fact that the device has failed (=1) and hence the disk capacity is set to 0.

Comment: But I thought that Amazon should detect it and replace bad partitions?

Comment: Thats because tossed is also set to 1 which implies that there is at least 1 block on this device that AWS cannot remove as it is unsafe to free their disk address.

Comment: From the docs :
Tossed = "Number of blocks that are ready to be deleted but are not yet removed because it is not safe to free their disk addresses. If the addresses were freed immediately, a pending transaction could write to the same location on disk. Therefore, these tossed blocks are released as of the next commit. Disk blocks might be marked as tossed, for example, when a table column is dropped, during INSERT operations, or during disk-based query operations."

Comment: Do you know if this will impact the total available disk space?

Comment: I am not completely sure about the internals of how AWS treats failed disk blocks/partitions but going by the definition looks like it may not since these are logical partitions with 0 capacity.